# Clojure's ref vs atom in concurrency

Tags: concurrency, clojure

```
(ns learnclojure.core)

(def acct1 (atom 1000 :validator #(>= % 0)))
(def acct2 (atom 1000 :validator #(>= % 0)))

(defn transfer [from-ac to-ac amt]
  (swap! to-ac + amt)
  (swap! from-ac - amt))

(dotimes [_ 10]
  (future (transfer acct2 acct1 100)))

(deref acct1)
(deref acct2)


(def acct1 (ref 1000 :validator #(>= % 0)))
(def acct2 (ref 1000 :validator #(>= % 0)))

(defn transfer [from-ac to-ac amt]
  (dosync
    (alter to-ac + amt)
    (alter from-ac - amt)))

(dotimes [_ 10]
  (future (transfer acct2 acct1 100)))

(deref acct1)
(deref acct2)
```

I have two Clojure code changing states concurrently.
The first one that uses atom (line 3 - 14) seems to be working fine, whereas the second one that uses ref (line 17 and 29) shows random results. What might be wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last `(deref acct1) (deref acct2)` forms are evaluated before the futures are done executing.

What's more, the result is inconsistent because the reads are not coordinated; if you had written something like `(dosync [(deref acct1) (deref acct2)])` the sum would always be 2000.

By the way, I strongly recommend you do not re-define the `#'transfer`, `#'acct1` and `#'acct2` vars for this kind of concurrency experiment; choose different names :)